# Convert .jl text rows to utf-8 json in Python 3+

Tags: utf-8, pycharm, python-3.6

I'm using a .jl file that has data as rows of strings. It seems when the file was created, the data was not saved in utf-8, and this is causing me some problems.

Python 3 should be automatically converting strings to utf-8, and my development environment is PyCharm, which I've configured to display utf-8 encoding.

It looks like the data itself is the problem, being saved as raw strings.

Any ideas what I can do? Any packages I can use? .decode() doesn't seem to work?

Comment: What's a .jl file? Can you show a snippet of the content – what it looks like now, and what it should look like?

Comment: Also note that Python doesn't "automatically convert strings to UTF-8" in all situations. There are different defaults; for `str.encode` it's indeed UTF-8, but for `print` and `open`, the default encoding is platform-dependent.